# Incosistent notation of complex number

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, format, complex-numbers

The output of a second multiplication mixes formats of real and imaginary parts of a complex number.

Code I used:

```
import numpy as np
tmp1=np.zeros((3,3),dtype='complex64')
tmp2=np.zeros((3,3),dtype='complex64')
M=np.array([[  2.29e-03 -5.23e-23j,   1.62e-03 +1.37e-23j,   9.14e-06 +4.84e-03j],
 [  1.62e-03 -5.95e-23j,  -1.36e-03 +1.92e-23j,  -5.29e-06 +2.87e-03j],
 [  9.14e-06 -4.84e-03j,  -5.29e-06 -2.87e-03j,   9.63e-01 -3.11e-03j]])
print 'M'
print M
a=np.diag([1.,1.,1j])
print 'a'
print(a)  
print 'a^+'
b=np.diag([1,1,-1j])
print(b)
tmp1=np.dot(M,a)
print 'tmp1'
print(tmp1)
tmp2=np.dot(b,tmp1)
print 'C'
print(tmp2)
```

The output is:

```
M
[[  2.29000000e-03 -5.23000000e-23j   1.62000000e-03 +1.37000000e-23j
    9.14000000e-06 +4.84000000e-03j]
 [  1.62000000e-03 -5.95000000e-23j  -1.36000000e-03 +1.92000000e-23j
   -5.29000000e-06 +2.87000000e-03j]
 [  9.14000000e-06 -4.84000000e-03j  -5.29000000e-06 -2.87000000e-03j
    9.63000000e-01 -3.11000000e-03j]]
a
[[ 1.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  1.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+1.j]]
a^+
[[ 1.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  1.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.-1.j]]
tmp1
[[  2.29000000e-03 -5.23000000e-23j   1.62000000e-03 +1.37000000e-23j
   -4.84000000e-03 +9.14000000e-06j]
 [  1.62000000e-03 -5.95000000e-23j  -1.36000000e-03 +1.92000000e-23j
   -2.87000000e-03 -5.29000000e-06j]
 [  9.14000000e-06 -4.84000000e-03j  -5.29000000e-06 -2.87000000e-03j
    3.11000000e-03 +9.63000000e-01j]]
C
[[ 0.00229 -5.23000000e-23j  0.00162 +1.37000000e-23j
  -0.00484 +9.14000000e-06j]
 [ 0.00162 -5.95000000e-23j -0.00136 +1.92000000e-23j
  -0.00287 -5.29000000e-06j]
 [-0.00484 -9.14000000e-06j -0.00287 +5.29000000e-06j
   0.96300 -3.11000000e-03j]]
```

In C you can see that the real part is presented in decimal representation and the imaginary part is in the scientific representation. Any idea why this happens? Is this a bug in Python (2.7.10) or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing `numpy` print function(s) in action, trying to display the array in a consistent, but compact manner.

The real part of `tmp2` prints this way because all values can be shown (to 3 significant figures) without resorting to scientific notation

```
In [28]: tmp2.real
Out[28]: 
array([[ 0.00229,  0.00162, -0.00484],
       [ 0.00162, -0.00136, -0.00287],
       [-0.00484, -0.00287,  0.963  ]])
```

Make a copy, and make one element much smaller, and it switches to scientific notation:

```
In [29]: tmp3=tmp2.copy()
In [30]: tmp3[2,0]*= 1e-6
In [31]: tmp3.real
Out[31]: 
array([[  2.29000000e-03,   1.62000000e-03,  -4.84000000e-03],
       [  1.62000000e-03,  -1.36000000e-03,  -2.87000000e-03],
       [ -4.84000000e-09,  -2.87000000e-03,   9.63000000e-01]])
```

See the doc for `np.set_printoptions` for more details on parameters that control the print.

And apparently, it is choosing the format for the real and imaginary parts separately.

To block all scientific notation:

```
In [38]: np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
In [39]: tmp2
Out[39]: 
array([[ 0.00229-0.j        ,  0.00162+0.j        , -0.00484+0.00000914j],
       [ 0.00162-0.j        , -0.00136+0.j        , -0.00287-0.00000529j],
       [-0.00484-0.00000914j, -0.00287+0.00000529j,  0.96300-0.00311j   ]])
```

This `print` display is largely for your convenience during code development.  When writing to a file you probably want to use a function like `savetxt`.  See its doc for information on setting the format.  I believe it specifically talks about handling complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify [particular formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting)  Python tries to choose the most easily-understood representation of numbers while presenting as much precision as it can and using not too much space. So this is expected.

Comment: As the transformations I am performing on this array are unitary, the numbers dont change in size. The only thing that happens is that real and imaginary parts get swapped around. Now take a look at the tmp1 array and compare it to C. Why is the notation consistent in tmp1 and not in C? I dont see an explanation of this in your link sorry.